# Remove the weight_orig in Pytorch after Pruning a model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pruning

After a model is pruned in Pytorch, the saved model contains both the pruned weights and weight_orig. This causes the pruned model size to be greater than the unpruned model.
Is there a way to remove the weight_orig and reduce the pruned model size?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [offcial documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/pruning_tutorial.html#remove-pruning-re-parametrization), you can use `torch.nn.utils.prune.remove()` for this very purpose.
`remove()` removes the re-parametrization in terms of `weight_orig` and `weight_mask`, and removes the `forward_pre_hook`.
You'd use it like this:

```py
for module in model.modules():
    if isinstance(module, torch.nn.Conv2d):
        prune.remove(module,'weight')
    # etc...
```